# Is Cipher thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, encryption

Quite simply, can one instance of `javax.crypto.Cipher` (e.g. `Cipher.getInstance("RSA")`) be used from multiple threads, or do I need to stick multiple of them in a `ThreadLocal` (in my case)?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

No, it isn't. The instance is stateful. So you need to store it threadlocal, or to obtain a new instance on every encrypt/decrypt call, or to wrap it in a `synchronized(cipher)` block.

Threadsafety is usually mentioned in javadocs as "[is thread safe](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20thread%20safe%22%20site:https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase)" or "[is **not** thread safe](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20not%20thread%20safe%22%20site:https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase)". This is not the case for [`Cipher`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html), so you should not assume it to be threadsafe.

Answer (score 10):

Even if a Cipher was thread-safe, it would not really be useful to use it from multiple threads concurrently.

The bytes you put into and get out of the Cipher (via its `update` and `finish` methods) are a continuous stream. This means, on the other end, they have to be passed in the same order to make any sense. This is easiest to accomplish if you have only one thread doing this.

If you are using multiple threads, you usually would want to call `reset` between the calls - and then you will need external synchronization anyways.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't use Cipher objects from multiple threads without synchronization. When you look at the API, there are methods which can only work by changing internal state, such as `init()` and `update()`. That makes them implicitly non-thread-safe.

Comment: From JavaDocs for Cipher init(): "Note that when a Cipher object is initialized, it loses all previously-acquired state. In other words, initializing a Cipher is equivalent to creating a new instance of that Cipher and initializing it." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#init(int,%20java.security.Key)

Comment: Rightly said @ddso

Answer (score 6):

Cipher is not thread safe.

If you use multithreading for performance and don't want to do synchronization, you can use Jasypt (http://www.jasypt.org/general-usage.html) it has pooled encryptors: PooledPBEByteEncryptor, PooledPBEStringEncryptor.

If synchronization is ok for you and you use Spring. You can use Encryptors (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/encrypt/Encryptors.html). They do synchronization internally to access Cipher.