# AES-GCM: AEADBadTagException: mac check in GCM failed

Tags: java, aes-gcm

While trying to implement AES-GCM for the first time, we are facing issue in generating AuthenticationTag, Encrypted cipher & GCM mac check fails in the end. For out current implementation `tag[]` is being populated but `byte[] encrypted` remains empty. And because of this `cipher.doFinal(data1, offset)` gives '`mac check in GCM failed`'. It appears to be some issue around the size of byte arrays, can someone please share on what basis should the output buffer size be determined? Should this be done in chunks?

Any pointers/links to AES-GCM implementation will be highly appreciated.

Following is our implementation:

```
public class GCMTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //***********************************************************
        //Key
        byte[] key = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest("1234567890123456".getBytes("UTF-8"));//this is the random key

        //Iv
        SecureRandom srand = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        byte[] iv = new byte[256];
        srand.nextBytes(iv);

        //Input
        byte[] data="inputPlainText".getBytes();

        final GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(16 * Byte.SIZE, iv);

        //***********************************************************
        //Encryption
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", new BouncyCastleProvider());
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"), gcmParameterSpec);

        cipher.updateAAD("MyAAD".getBytes("UTF-8"));

        //Encrypted output
        final byte[] encrypted = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(data.length)];
        cipher.update(data, 0, data.length, encrypted, 0);  //Not being updated for current data. 

        //Tag output
        byte[] tag = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(data.length)];
        cipher.doFinal(tag, 0);


        //***********************************************************
        //Decryption
        final SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, gcmParameterSpec);

        cipher.updateAAD("MyAAD".getBytes("UTF-8"));

        //What size should be assigned to outputBuffer?
        final byte[] data1 = new byte[256];

        int offset = cipher.update(encrypted, 0, encrypted.length, data1, 0);
        cipher.update(tag, 0, tag.length, data1, offset);
        cipher.doFinal(data1, offset);

        boolean isValid = checkEquals(data, data1);
        System.out.println("isValid :"+isValid);
    }

    private static boolean checkEquals(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
        int diff = a.length ^ b.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length && i < b.length; i++)
            diff |= a[i] ^ b[i];
        return diff == 0;
    }
}
```

It gives following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: mac check in GCM failed
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$AEADGenericBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2068)
    at GCMTest.main(GCMTest.java:56)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Sometimes this can be caused by threading issues: [`Cipher` isn't thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957406/is-cipher-thread-safe).

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula what kind of issues?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky `Cipher` clearly isn't thread safe according to the question I mentioned, so what I meant is that the exception mentioned in this question might be caused by accessing the `cipher` instance by different threads at the same time. I've had this issue and it stopped happening after I added synchronization in my code. But I've had all sorts of issues while using these APIs on Android, so it might also have been something else.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula Thanks.  Have you found a reliable solution to your OP which works for you on Android?  I'm still hunting for a viable solution.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I haven't found a reliable way to use the Android Keystore APIs without running into sad random crashes on some specific devices, unfortunately.

Answer (score 11):

I was having this same issue. For me, it had to do with encoding the string. I ended up doing:

1. Get ASCII bytes from string you want to encrypt (UTF-8 in your case)
2. Encrypt bytes
3. Encode bytes in Base64 string

Then to decrypt string I did:

4. Decode encrypted string to Base64 bytes
5. Decrypt Base64 bytes
6. Create new string using ASCII.

Here is the code :

```
private String encrypt(String src) {
    byte[] srcBytes = src.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, secureRandom);

    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(srcBytes);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[12 + cipherText.length];

    System.arraycopy(ivBytes, 0, encryptedBytes, 0, 12);
    System.arraycopy(cipherText, 0, encryptedBytes, 12, cipherText.length);

    return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}

private String decrypt(String encryptedString) {
    byte[] encryptedBytes = Base64.decode(encryptedString, Base64.DEFAULT);

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new GCMParameterSpec(128, encryptedBytes, 0, 12));
    byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes, 12, encryptedBytes.length-12);

    return Base64.encodeToString(decryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Any variables I didn't include how to initialize them can be inferred from the java docs. I was trying to do this in Android so I'm not sure how different it is. I found this post to be incredibly helpful: [Java AES/GCM/NoPadding - What is cipher.getIV() giving me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851612/java-aes-gcm-nopadding-what-is-cipher-getiv-giving-me/31863209#31863209)

Comment: What is **length-12**??

Comment: Google, encryption iv. The first 12 bytes are only used for encrypting. But in this case, I'm not entirely sure the IV bytes are random bytes

Answer (score 1):

you should update section code

error section code:

```
//What size should be assigned to outputBuffer?
final byte[] data1 = new byte[256];

int offset = cipher.update(encrypted, 0, encrypted.length, data1, 0);
cipher.update(tag, 0, tag.length, data1, offset);
cipher.doFinal(data1, offset);
```

update the new code:

```
final byte[] data1 = new byte[encrypted.length];
int offset = cipher.update(encrypted, 0, encrypted.length, data1, 0);
offset += cipher.update(tag, 0, tag.length, data1, offset);
cipher.doFinal(data1, offset);
```

Comment: This one was really relevant for my case, but in addition to this I need to remove the `cipher.updateAAD("MyAAD".getBytes("UTF-8"));` line; basically the `cipher.updateAAD()`.

Comment: cipher.update(tag, 0, tag.length, data1, offset); what is the tag here. In encryption the auth tag is generated automatically?