# Having issues with decrypting AES-GCM

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, aes

I've been trying to figure out my way around the java security/crypto libraries and i believe I've made some progress with understanding what's going on. I think I managed to get the encryption part working. In my encrypt method if i simply try to return 
`return new String(encryptedText, "UTF-8");`
I get some unreadable jumble which looks like encrypted text.
The issue comes about when I try to instead of returning that, going on and calling decrypt and going cleartext --> encrypt --> decrypt
here is everything i have

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class AES256_GCM {

public String encrypt(String cleartext) {

    try 
    {
        // encoding format needs thought
        byte[] clearTextbytes = cleartext.getBytes("UTF-8");
        final SecureRandom secureKeyRandomness = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
        final KeyGenerator AES_keyInstance = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        AES_keyInstance.init(128, secureKeyRandomness);
        final SecretKey secretKey = AES_keyInstance.generateKey();
        final Cipher AES_cipherInstance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        AES_cipherInstance.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] encryptedText = AES_cipherInstance.doFinal(clearTextbytes);
        return decrypt(encryptedText, secretKey);
    } 
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "something went wrong with encrypt";
} // encrypt.

public String decrypt(byte[] encryptedText, SecretKey secretKey) {
    try 
    {
        final Cipher AES_cipherInstance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        AES_cipherInstance.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] decryptedText = AES_cipherInstance.doFinal(encryptedText);
        return new String(decryptedText, "UTF-8");
    } 
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "something went wrong with decrypt";
} // decrypt.

} // AES256_GCM.
```

So i call encrypt with some cleartext and try to return back the cleartext to make sure it works. Here's what im dealing with, Anything with javafx in there is probably irrelevant. I get no issues returning the encrypted string, its only the decrypted string throwing this.

"something went wrong with decrypt" is returned followed by:

```
    java.security.InvalidKeyException: Parameters missing
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:470)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineInit(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:801)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:863)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1248)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1185)
    at PackageName.AES256_GCM.decrypt(AES256_GCM.java:49)
    at PackageName.AES256_GCM.encrypt(AES256_GCM.java:36)
    at com.javafxpractice.PackageName.letsEncrypt.letsEnc(letsEncrypt.java:10)
    at com.javafxpractice.PackageName.Controller.onClicked(Controller.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Parameters missing
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:470)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineInit(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:801)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:863)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1248)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1185)
    at PackageName.AES256_GCM.decrypt(AES256_GCM.java:49)
    at PackageName.AES256_GCM.encrypt(AES256_GCM.java:36)
    at com.javafxpractice.PackageName.letsEncrypt.letsEnc(letsEncrypt.java:10)
    at com.javafxpractice.PackageName.Controller.onEnter(Controller.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:149)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$352(GlassViewEventHandler.java:248)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The Java example [here](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples) gives a nice clear understanding of the steps involved in using GCM mode.

Comment: Note my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15712409/589259) wrt handling the exceptions. Note that `AES_keyInstance` should be named `aesKey` if you use common Java coding guidelines.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I actually had that page bookmarked as I remember you posting it on reddit. However it also deals with a custom password and at the time while i was trying to debug my problem, i didnt want to mix the future 'custom password' concepts with the issue I had in case i get confused. Trying to slowly learn everything from ground up and that will be useful very soon. Also a funny detail, I see that we both share a dislike for Python and now it makes sense why in your initial reddit post Python wasnt supported and everyone in the thread was questioning why and confused.

Comment: @tempacct Heh, yeah, sometimes you just gotta do what you gotta do.  I've never been a fan!

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark You think I can get an email or a way to contact you? no specific reason really, I'd like to keep in touch.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark gmail? well that's surprising.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Added GCMParameterSpec inplace of IVParameterSpec. A nice discussion as a precursor up for the code edit below is [Java AES/GCM/NoPadding - What is cipher.getIV() giving me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851612/java-aes-gcm-nopadding-what-is-cipher-getiv-giving-me)

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import java.security.*;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class EncryptDecrypt1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EncryptDecrypt1 a = new EncryptDecrypt1();
        String encrypted = a.encrypt("My text");
        System.out.println(encrypted);      
    }
    public String encrypt(String cleartext) throws Exception {

        try 
        {
            // encoding format needs thought
            byte[] clearTextbytes = cleartext.getBytes("UTF-8");
            final SecureRandom secureKeyRandomness = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
            final KeyGenerator AES_keyInstance = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            AES_keyInstance.init(128, secureKeyRandomness);
            final SecretKey secretKey = AES_keyInstance.generateKey();
            final Cipher AES_cipherInstance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            AES_cipherInstance.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            byte[] encryptedText = AES_cipherInstance.doFinal(clearTextbytes);

            byte[] iv = AES_cipherInstance.getIV();
            byte[] message = new byte[12 + clearTextbytes.length + 16];
            System.arraycopy(iv, 0, message, 0, 12);
            System.arraycopy(encryptedText, 0, message, 12, encryptedText.length);

            return decrypt(message, secretKey);
        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "something went wrong with encrypt";
    } // encrypt.

    public String decrypt(byte[] encryptedText, SecretKey secretKey) throws Exception {
        try 
        {
            final Cipher AES_cipherInstance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            GCMParameterSpec params = new GCMParameterSpec(128, encryptedText, 0, 12);
            AES_cipherInstance.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, params);
            byte[] decryptedText = AES_cipherInstance.doFinal(encryptedText, 12, encryptedText.length - 12);
            return new String(decryptedText, "UTF-8");
        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "something went wrong with decrypt";
    }

}
```

Comment: Now encrypt throws an exception with "java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Unsupported parameter"

I can include the full report if you'd like.

Comment: before decrypt was simply throwing "java.security.InvalidKeyException: Parameters missing" it seems like.

Comment: Edited the code with working set. Added GCMParameterSpec. Nice discussion to back the code edit is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851612/java-aes-gcm-nopadding-what-is-cipher-getiv-giving-me

Comment: ok now this works but i have to go figure out wtf just happened. So many new topics introduced here. thx

Comment: Just getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid buffer arguments