# Android Passing IV parameters Encryption /Decryption text

Tags: android, encryption, aes-gcm

I Hope that you can help me related my code.

Im trying to pass parameters IV to Encrypt/ Decryt

Encrypt Funcion:

I try to concatenate text; IV

```
encryptedText.setText(Base64.encodeToString(vals, Base64.DEFAULT) + ";" + (Base64.encodeToString(encryptionIv, Base64.DEFAULT)));
```

I think that is working fine , as the image represents.

```
 public void encryptString(String alias) {
        try {

            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            keyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey secretKey = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, null);
            String initialText = startText.getText().toString();
            if(initialText.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter text in the 'Initial Text'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            Cipher inCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

            inCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

            byte[] src= initialText.getBytes("UTF-8");

            byte[] iv = inCipher.getIV();
            assert iv.length == 12;
            byte[] cipherText = inCipher.doFinal(src);
            assert cipherText.length == src.length + 16;
            byte[] message = new byte[12 + src.length + 16];
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(
                    outputStream, inCipher);
            cipherOutputStream.write(src);
            cipherOutputStream.close();
            byte [] vals = outputStream.toByteArray();
            encryptedText.setText(Base64.encodeToString(vals, Base64.DEFAULT));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception " + e.getMessage() + " occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
    }
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Could you helpme with an example to get decryption works fine?

Thanks for youl help

Updated: Hello , Im trying to pass the IV as the example:

My code here:

```
 public void encryptString(String alias) {
        try {
            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
            RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey();

            String initialText = startText.getText().toString();
            if(initialText.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter text in the 'Initial Text' widget", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            Cipher inCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "AndroidOpenSSL");
            inCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(
                    outputStream, inCipher);
            cipherOutputStream.write(initialText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            cipherOutputStream.close();

            byte [] vals = outputStream.toByteArray();
            encryptedText.setText(Base64.encodeToString(vals, Base64.DEFAULT));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception " + e.getMessage() + " occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
    }
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

NEW Updated:

Encryption code

```
public void encryptString(String alias) {
        try {

            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            keyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey secretKey = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, null);
            String initialText = startText.getText().toString();
            if(initialText.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter text in the 'Initial Text'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            Cipher inCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

            inCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

            byte[] src= initialText.getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] iv = inCipher.getIV();
            assert iv.length == 12;
            byte[] cipherText = inCipher.doFinal(src);
            assert cipherText.length == src.length + 16;
            byte[] message = new byte[12 + src.length + 16];
            System.arraycopy(iv, 0, message, 0, 12);
            System.arraycopy(cipherText, 0, message, 12, cipherText.length);
            //ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(
              //      outputStream, inCipher);
            //cipherOutputStream.write(message);
            //cipherOutputStream.close();
            //byte [] vals = outputStream.toByteArray();
            encryptedText.setText(Base64.encodeToString(message, Base64.DEFAULT));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception " + e.getMessage() + " occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
    }
```

Decryption code: ( Not working)

```
public void decryptString(String alias) {
        try {

            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            keyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey secretKey = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, null);
            String cipherText = encryptedText.getText().toString();

            byte[] src = cipherText.getBytes();
            byte[] message = new byte[12 + src.length + 16];
            Cipher output = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            GCMParameterSpec params = new GCMParameterSpec(128, message, 0, 12);
            output.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, params);
          //  output.doFinal(message, 12, message.length - 12);



            CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(
             new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT)), output);
            ArrayList<Byte> values = new ArrayList<>();
           int nextByte;
           while ((nextByte = cipherInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                values.add((byte)nextByte);
            }

          byte[] bytes = new byte[values.size()];
         for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            bytes[i] = values.get(i).byteValue();
         }

            String finalText = new String(bytes, 0, bytes.length, "UTF-8");
            decryptedText.setText(finalText);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception " + e.getMessage() + " occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
    }
```

Could you help me with the error shows in the image?

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

<<---UPDATED SOLUTION-->

Encript function:

```
 public void encryptString(String alias) {
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            keyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey secretKey = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, null);
            String initialText = startText.getText().toString();
            if(initialText.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter text in the 'Initial Text'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            Cipher inCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            inCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            byte[] src= initialText.getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] iv = inCipher.getIV();
            assert iv.length == 12;
            byte[] cipherText = inCipher.doFinal(src);
            assert cipherText.length == src.length + 16;
            byte[] message = new byte[12 + src.length + 16];
            System.arraycopy(iv, 0, message, 0, 12);
            System.arraycopy(cipherText, 0, message, 12, cipherText.length);
            encryptedText.setText(Base64.encodeToString(message, Base64.DEFAULT));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception " + e.getMessage() + " occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
    }
```

Decrypt Function:

```
    public void decryptString(String alias) {
        try {

            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            keyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey secretKey = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, null);
            String cipherText = encryptedText.getText().toString();
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            byte[] nonceCiphertextTag = Base64.decode(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);
            GCMParameterSpec params = new GCMParameterSpec(128, nonceCiphertextTag, 0, 12);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, params);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(nonceCiphertextTag, 12, nonceCiphertextTag.length - 12);
            String finalText = new String(decrypted, 0, decrypted.length, "UTF-8");
            decryptedText.setText(finalText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception " + e.getMessage() + " occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot for the help @Topaco

Comment: `encryptedText.getText()` seems to be just a string with two Base64 encoded parts separated by a semicolon. Why can't you separate them, e.g. with `split()`? Then you can Base64 decode the two parts and process/apply them.

Comment: Regarding the use of the IV for decryption take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31851612/9014097). You essentially create a `GCMParameterSpec()` which encapsulates the IV and which is passed as 3rd parameter to `cipher.init()`.

Comment: By the way, the linked example also shows a more efficient concatenation, namely on byte level. Here, no separator is required because the separation is based on the known lengths (e.g. 12 bytes for the IV/nonce in the context of GCM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest posted encryption code, nonce, ciphertext and tag are concatenated and Base64 encoded, in the following called `nonceCiphertextTagB64`.

When decrypting

- `nonceCiphertextTagB64` must first be Base64 decoded to `nonceCiphertextTag`,
- the nonce must be encapsulated in a `GCMParameterSpec` instance; the nonce are the first 12 bytes of `nonceCiphertextTag`,
- a cipher instance for `AES/GCM/NoPadding` must be created, which is initialized with the key and the `GCMParameterSpec` instance in decryption mode,
- the concatenation of ciphertext and tag is decrypted; the concatenation of ciphertext and tag is the data after the nonce.

In the following example implementation, with respect to a repro, the 32 bytes key `01234567890123456789012345678901` is used (instead of a key from the key store). The ciphertext was created with the posted code for encryption using the same key and the plaintext *The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog*:

```java
...
String nonceCiphertextTagB64 =
        "UpyxMnzPrw+zJGANL4wBbaC+UX5KnMKYwhR0u2iF/GDCcU38YKWlvJp1zJ+mrN0POP7lz9y+eweH\n" +
        "vIxAH4R4U3At8T0fVe0=";
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec("01234567890123456789012345678901".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),"AES");
byte[] nonceCiphertextTag = Base64.decode(nonceCiphertextTagB64, Base64.DEFAULT);
GCMParameterSpec params = new GCMParameterSpec(128, nonceCiphertextTag, 0, 12);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, params);
byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(nonceCiphertextTag, 12, nonceCiphertextTag.length - 12);
System.out.println(new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); // The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
...
```

The output is:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```