# Is it okay to concatenate iv and auth tag along with token created using aes-256-gcm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, encryption, cryptography

I'm generating an access token for users and saving it in the user's browser cookie, i'm wondering if making iv and auth tag public like this is safe or not?

When i create a token i make it like `iv.token.authTag`

Here's my code for encrypting and decrypting the token

```js
export const encryptAccessToken = (user: User): Result<string> => {
  try {
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(8).toString('hex');
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', env.CIPHER_SECRET, iv);
    const payload = {
      created_at: dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'),
      expires_at: dayjs().add(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'),
      user,
    };
    const cipherStr = cipher.update(JSON.stringify(payload), 'utf-8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex');
    const accessToken = [iv, cipherStr, cipher.getAuthTag().toString('hex')].join('.');

    return {
      ok: true,
      value: accessToken,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return { ok: false, error };
  }
};

export const decryptAccessToken = (accessToken: string): Result<AccessTokenPayload> => {
  try {
    const [iv, cipher, authTag] = accessToken.split('.');
    if (!iv || !cipher || !authTag) {
      throw new Error('Invalid access token format');
    }

    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', env.CIPHER_SECRET, iv);
    decipher.setAuthTag(Buffer.from(authTag, 'hex'));
    const payloadStr = decipher.update(cipher, 'hex', 'utf-8') + decipher.final('utf-8');

    return { ok: true, value: JSON.parse(payloadStr) };
  } catch (error) {
    return { ok: false, error };
  }
};
```

Comment: Unlike the key, the IV/nonce and tag are not secret. It is common practice to concatenate IV/nonce, ciphertext and tag (typically also in this order).

Comment: Concatenation is usually done on byte level without separator (instead of concatenation of hex encoded values separated by a delimiter). Separation on the decryption side is based on the known lengths of IV/nonce and tag (so no separator is required).

Comment: In addition, an IV/nonce of 12 bytes and not 16 bytes is recommended for GCM. For this, a random 12 byte sequence should be used and not a half-length byte sequence that is blown up to the double by hex encoding.

Comment: @Topaco oh okay thanks! can you show an example how concatenation at byte level would work?

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/KGW

Comment: @Topaco just one more thing, is there a way to keep the encrypted token characters limited to alphanumeric?

Comment: when creating the token if i update it to `Buffer.concat([....]).toString('hex')` i'm able to get just alphanumeric characters but i'm wondering if it makes it unsafe?

Comment: Instead of Base64 encoding you can also use hex encoding, both are [binary-to-text encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding). Base64 has the advantage that it is more efficient (75%) than hex encoding (50%). Efficiency means the ratio of number of input bits to number of output bits. There is no difference in security.

Comment: The question is language agnostic. You can get more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31851612/589259)