# Is javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec thread safe?

Tags: java, encryption

I intend to use it in a spring bean as a static field, and init it inside a post construct method.
A service class will inject this encryption bean and call a method exposed by it to encrypt a string using a cipher (javax.crypto.Cipher) (cipher will be initalized using the SecretKeySpec ).

Note: A new cipher instance will be fetched each time within the encrypt string method.

Edit:
As @Savior noted, the field (SecretKeySpec) should not be denoted as static. If SecretKeySpec is thread safe then I will make it a bean in a configuration class and inject it into the encryption bean (marking it as a private final field and injecting it via constructor)

Comment: Could be similar: [Is Cipher thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957406/is-cipher-thread-safe)

Comment: Side note: don't do _a spring bean as a static field_, and definitely don't do _init it inside a post construct method_.

Comment: @akuzminykh Appreciate the link to that post. Cipher is not thread safe, however I was wondering if the SecretKeySpec used to get a new instance of a cipher is.

Comment: @Savior Apologies if the description was confusing. The spring bean is not the static field, the SecretKeySpec field inside the "encryption bean" will be marked as static. The init will be used to initialize the SecretKeySpec field of the bean.

Comment: Yeah, no, that was clear. Don't do that. If Spring is managing all your injections, there's no reason for anything to be `static`.

Comment: @Savior Thank you for the feedback. If SecretKeySpec is thread-safe, then I can declare it as a bean in a configuration class and inject it into the encryption bean (marking SecretKeySpec as private final and injecting it via the constructor)

Comment: Yes, SecretKeySpec is thread-safe, for the simple reason that it's immutable.

Comment: Thanks @PresidentJamesK.Polk

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk almost immutable, see my answer... there is the `Destroyable`  interface...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: Good catch, I missed that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is. It's pretty easy to see why: there are no methods (bar one, see below) that change the state of a `SecretKeySpec` instance. In other words, the class is usually immutable, even if this is not specifically mentioned in the class description. Immutable classes are by definition thread safe. Actually, most if not all `Key` implementations are generally immutable.

There is one method that breaks the immutability (which I forgot about), and that's the newer [`Key.destroy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/javax/security/auth/Destroyable.html#destroy()) method. Don't worry though, that's not called by `Cipher` or any other function to my knowledge. Furthermore, the method is not implemented by `SecretKeySpec` (checked in the OpenJDK up to version 14).

---

As also noted in the comments, you should never put any dynamic information into static fields. Instead just share a reference otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @Maarten Bodewes would up vote but don't have enough  reputation.